# Automatically scale up to high instance class if close to memory limit?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Our app engine application runs on a low end instance class, using just 256mb RAM.

However, due to a current bug with Cloud Storage not working with the PHP Zip Archive class, we have to use an in-memory approach for creating ZIP files, which means, with a handful of large files, the instance simply runs out of memory.

Other then setting the app on a higher instance and leaving it there, is there a way to set the instance to a low class, then have it automatically scale up to a higher class i.e. one with more RAM, when the instance approaches the memory limit of the lower class?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this, but I think there is a better solution.

You can create your own [microservice](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/an-overview-of-app-engine) for creating ZIP files that uses an instance with higher memory.  If you only use this instance occasionally, then you should be able to spin it up when needed and not have to pay a lot for instance hours.